# Python Polars way to copy data frame to clipboard

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars data frame. I would like to do a simple copy to clipboard natively to avoid converting to a Pandas data frame and dealing with the memory costs associated with the conversion. I scoured the Polars documentation and I am fairly confident there is no way to do this natively yet. If I am mistaken, could someone point me in the right direction? If there is no such function, I thought it would be useful to leave this as an open question until such functionality has been built.

Here's a sample attempting this in Polars and accomplishing it in Pandas:

```
import pandas
import polars as rs

>>> rs.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 
...               'col2': ["a", "b"]})
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ a    │
│ 2    ┆ b    │
└──────┴──────┘
>>> df = rs.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 
...                    'col2': ["a", "b"]})
>>> df.to_clipboard()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_clipboard'
>>> df.to_pandas().to_clipboard(index=False)
>>>
```

Comment: If you want to do a feature request then that should go [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues)

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9902